# cannot convert xarray dataframe to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I need to use some *.nc files with pandas and I am strugguling with conversion.
Here is the DataSet DS1:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 51, longitude: 51, time: 47)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 15.1 15.2 15.3 15.4 ... 19.8 19.9 20.0 35.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 34.9 34.8 34.7 34.6 ... 30.1 30.0 9.9498e-40
  * time       (time) object 1981-01-01 02:00:00 ... -243069-06-09 17:00:00
Data variables:
    u10        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 nan nan nan ... nan nan nan
    v10        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 nan nan nan ... nan nan nan
    t2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 nan nan nan ... nan nan nan
    tp         (time, latitude, longitude) float32 nan nan nan ... nan nan nan
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2021-07-03 16:40:01 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.20.0: /opt/ecmw...
```

with

```
DS1.to_dataframe()
```

I get error:

```
NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time
```

My concern is that `time` coordinate `-243069-06-09 17:00:00` is cause of this error, since is completly out of range I expected in file.

[Here is a link to original file.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMkJcWY42yZqIdQe7Rfg?e=vY2uJo)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried it with the file you've provided and it worked without any error. Do you transform the contents of the file before trying the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I resolved this by simply filtering out  negative time dimension with
`DS1.where(DS1.time>cftime.DatetimeGregorian(1980, 1, 1,1),drop=True).to_dataframe()`

Not sure know how it creates this additional dimension, but it solved my problem.

Thanks for you time and effort @timus.